# Add multiple values in where clause in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause, where-in, grocery-crud

I want to add multiple values in where clause.

------------As In Sql , we do like this------------------

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

---

How to use this in grocery crud?

Answer (score 2):

The WHERE clause in GroceryCrud works exactly like codeigniter's WHERE clause:

```
$this->db->where_in('columnname', $arrayvalues);
```

Hope this helps you, don't hesitate to ask further questions =)

GroceryCrud Documentaion [WHERE](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/where)

Answer (score 0):

use `or_where` instead of `where` .

e.g

```
function example_with_or_where() {

    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->where('productName','Motorcycle');
    $crud->or_where('productName','Car');
    $crud->or_where('productName','Bicycle');

    $crud->set_table('products');
    $crud->columns('productName','buyPrice');

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

detail [here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/or_where)